# "Should" instead of "were to"

Tags: conditional-constructions, inversion

Can we use "**should**" instead of "**[were to](http://www.englishpage.com/conditional/wereto.html)**" and vice versa? I've noticed that mostly they mean the same thing in the subjunctive and the conditional clauses. Especially when the "**were to**" isn't in the *if-clause* but an *[inverse conditional clause](http://www.tolearnenglish.com/exercises/exercise-english-2/exercise-english-89063.php)* instead.

What I mean to say is that these mean the same:

- Should we get more money next month, we would be able to buy an oven.
- Were we to get more money next month, we would be able to buy an oven.

But my British friend says that **"should + would"** is incorrect grammar and "**will**" should be used instead. I cannot find a way to prove that my examples are correct. And he says the inversion is too formal and best be avoided. His variants are:

- If we should get more money next month, we will be able to buy an oven.
- If we were to get more money next month, we would be able to buy an oven.

That makes them completely different in meaning.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, *should* functions as the first conditional. You may think of it as follows:

> If we happen to get more money next month, we will be able to buy an
>   oven.

That's why *will* sounds correct there and *would* doesn't.

*Were to* is unrealistic condition in subjunctive, that's why you need *would* there. You could rephrase it in this way:

> If we got more money next month, we would be able to buy an oven.

[This article](https://www.englishpractice.com/grammar/conditional-sentences-2/) partially covers the topic (as regards *should*)

As for inversion, it sounds formal indeed.